# PHP pattern matching a literal single quote

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex pattern that causing me some problems:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/',  $value);
```

For some reason this pattern is not allowing the single quote (') character to return true.

I.E

`dog` returns true

`'dog'` returns false - but should return true

I've searched fairly extensively but so far I'm not seeing anything that would explain this.

--

Edited with the code as requested:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/', $field['php_population']) && !empty($field['php_population'])) {
                $e['errors']['php_population'] = 'long winded error message';
}
```

The method it's in is 70-80 lines so I didn't post it - let me know if you need the whole lot.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/20

Comment: Your regex works fine.

Comment: works fine, probably you have ` instead of `'`

Comment: OK I've gone as far as copying the version vks provided back into my code and I still cannot match strings containing single quotes, but the pattern must be basically correct. Does PHP need the quote mark treated differently? Great link btw, bookmarking that.

Comment: You might have one of the special fancy quotation characters, which don't get matched by `'` because their character code is different.

Comment: @greengreengrass could you post the full code in your question?

Comment: Try `[a-z']+` on `'dog'`. If you ever think the pattern is the problem, simplify it and force it to match. This saves hours of second guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/',"'dog'"); # <= return 1
echo preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/',urlencode("'dog'")); # <= return 0 as it test to %27dog%27
echo preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/',"dog"); # <= return 1
echo preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/',"'#dog'"); # <= return 0
?>
```

Your code works fine. I suspect your `$field['php_population']` to be urlencoded and the singlequote being replace by `%27` which does not match your regex. I would try with:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/', urldecode($field['php_population'])) && !empty($field['php_population'])) {
                $e['errors']['php_population'] = 'long winded error message';
}
```

Comment: Sorry no joy on that. However you did make me wonder if I was passing what I thought I was passing so I tried echoing the value of $field['php_population'] (not easy inside an ajax call) and I'm actually echoing \'dog\' for the input 'dog' right before the lines I pasted. I'm just looking up the stripping function - hopefully that will resolve it

Comment: OK resolved the problem by altering the code to  `if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z_\'\$\, ]{3,}$/', stripslashes($field['php_population']))`. Will be on the case with the hosting company tomorrow to know why the vps I ordered last month came with magic quotes switched on. Cheers for your help!